# Haskell: Graham Hutton Book on Parsing (page 178,CH 13.3)

Tags: parsing, haskell

Given the following Text:

> To allow the `Parser` type to be made into instances of classes, it is first redefined using newtype, with a dummy constructor called `P`:
>
> ```
> newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a,String)])
> ```
>
> A parser of this type can then be applied to an input string using a function that simply removes the dummy constructor:
>
> ```
> parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
> parse (P p) inp = p inp
> ```
>
> Our first parsing primitive is called item, which fails if the input string is empty, and succeeds with the first character as the result value otherwise:
>
> ```
> item :: Parser Char
> item = P (\inp -> case inp of [] -> [] (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)])
> ```

Question:
 Why do we need a "dummy variable" and how does it get used?

Comment: So that we can create instances, and thus are not forced to use the default ones. For example a function is an instance of `Functor`, but we do not necessarily want that for `Parser`.

Comment: It's explained [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype#The_short_version)

Answer (score 2):

"Dummy constructor" may not be the best choice of terminology.  It's not really much like a "dummy variable", for example.  The text probably makes more sense if you just delete the word "dummy" everywhere it appears.

The point of defining the newtype `Parser` and its associated constructor `P` is to allow type class instances to be defined for parsers in a convenient manner.

To see how this helps, suppose you took the alternate approach of defining a type synonym using the `type` keyword:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

This would make writing primitive parsing functions somewhat easier.  For example, the function `parse` above could be rewritten without needing to peel off the constructor:

```
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse p inp = p inp
```

You could even write the following!

```
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse = id
```

The `item` function would be much simpler, too:

```
item :: Parser Char
item [] = []
item (x:xs) = [(x,xs)]
```

The problem arises if you decide you want to define type class instances for parsers.  For example, a `Functor` instance is kind of nice, because it allows you to write something like:

```
data AST = Literal Int | ...

parseInt :: Parser AST
parseInt = Literal . read <$> digits
```

assuming that:

```
digits :: Parser String
```

is a parser that reads a string of digits.  What's happening here is that `Literal . read` is a function `String -> AST`, and `digits` is a `Parser String`, so we can combine them with the operator form of fmap `(<$>)` to create a `Parser AST` by applying the `Literal . read` function "under" the `Parser` type.

That assumes we can define a `Functor` instance for `Parser`, but there's a problem.  In standard Haskell (no extensions), instance definitions must be of the form:

```
instance SomeClass (T a1 a2 ... an) where ...
```

where `T` is type constructor and `a1..an` are type variables.  A type constructor is something that appears on the left-hand side of a `data` or `newtype` declaration (like `Int` or `Maybe`); but type *synonyms* defined with the `type` keyword aren't allowed.  So, we *can't* write:

```
instance Functor Parser where ...
```

While there are some extensions that relax the rules for defining instances, even with extensions, I believe it's impossible to define the instance we want here.  (Using `TypeSynonymInstances` and `FlexibleInstances`, we can define `instance Eq (Parser a)` if we want, but there's no way to define `instance Functor Parser`, even if we write out the definition of `Parser` explicitly.)  Even if we could, there would be horrifying problems with overlapping and orphan instances, because of the potential conflict between our instance and the built-in functor instance for general function types.

That's why we instead define `Parser` using a `newtype` (which requires a constructor, named `P` for convenience):

```
newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a,String)])
```

The newtype "contains" our real parser, which is a value of type `String -> [(a,String)]`, but by wrapping this value up into a newtype with a (data) constructor `P`, we make `Parser` a genuine *type* constructor, and instances can be defined directly:

```
instance Functor Parser where ...
```

The trade-off is that all the "primitive" functions are made more difficult to write, because they must unwrap and rewrap our "real" parsers by removing or adding the `P` constructor (e.g., the `item` from the book versus the `item` given earlier in my answer).

If the only benefit was a `Functor` instance, it probably wouldn't be worth it, but we can also define `Applicative`, `Alternative`, and `Monad` instances, and these are incredibly useful for parsers.  Ultimately, defining `Parser` as a `newtype` makes primitive parser functions (the things you'd find in a parser library) harder to write but easier to use with existing type class infrastructure.  Usually, people writing parser libraries decide that the trade-off of a slightly more complex library for easier usage is worth it.

Comment: Definitely impossible with a type synonym. The *type* of `fmap` for the bare function is utterly wrong for parsers.

Comment: It might or might not be worth mentioning that `type Parser = StateT String []` would actually work, but fails to enforce a potentially useful abstraction barrier.

Comment: Excellent explanation, Thank you.